# How do I get lazy streaming into the foldl'?

Tags: haskell, streaming, lazy-loading, space-leak, lazy-io

How does one make their own streaming code? I was generating about 1,000,000,000 random pairs of war decks, and I wanted them to be lazy streamed into a foldl', but I got a space leak! Here is the relevant section of code:

```
main = do
    games <- replicateM 1000000000 $ deal <$> sDeck --Would be a trillion, but Int only goes so high
    let res = experiment Ace games --experiment is a foldl'
    print res --res is tiny
```

When I run it with -O2, it first starts freezing up my computer, and then the program dies and the computer comes back to life (and Google Chrome then has the resources it needs to yell at me for using up all its resources.)

Note: I tried unsafeInterleaveIO, and it didn't work.

Full code is at: http://lpaste.net/109977

Comment: Are you sure the fold is what is eating up all the resources?  Have you tried profiling your code using a smaller number (so it doesn't crash) to find out exactly where the extra memory is being used?  It very well could be the `replicateM`, for example, or somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @bheklilr Well, it says turn.igo is doing the most allocating, but profilling says nothing about garbage collection.

Comment: No time to profile your code but suggest try a strict version of `Data.Map` used in `igo`.

Comment: I am not using `Data.Map` anywhere. `experiment` is using a strict intmap.

Answer (score 4):

`replicateM` doesn't do lazy streaming. If you need to stream results from monadic actions, you should use a library such as [`conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) or [`pipes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes).

Your example code could be written to support streaming with conduits like this:

```
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators as C

main = do
    let games = C.replicateM 1000000 $ deal <$> sDeck
    res <- games $$ C.foldl step Ace
    -- where step is the function you want to fold with
    print res
```

The `Data.Conduit.Combinators` module is from the [`conduit-combinators`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-combinators) package.

As a quick-and-dirty solution you could implement a streaming version of `replicateM` using lazy IO.

```
import System.IO.Unsafe

lazyReplicateIO :: Integer -> IO a -> IO [a] --Using Integer so I can make a trillion copies
lazyReplicateIO 0 _   = return []
lazyReplicateIO n act = do
    a <- act
    rest <- unsafeInterleaveIO $ lazyReplicateIO (n-1) act
    return $ a : rest
```

But I recommend using a proper streaming library.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent `pipes` solution is:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes

-- Assuming the following types
action :: IO A
acc    :: S
step   :: S -> A -> S
done   :: S -> B

main = do
    b <- Pipes.fold step acc done (Pipes.replicateM 1000000 action)
    print (b :: B)
```